# How can I make Google Adsense use US dollars

Tags: google-adsense

I have Google Adsense on my site and at some stage I was asked to select a currency and selected Australian dollars. However I would prefer to go back to US dollars as that is where most of the advertisers are from and so the exchange rate doesn't affect reporting.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. See [this help document](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139783). The only way to change currency is to close your account and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the situation has changed since [@Josh Curren](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/103/josh-curren) posted his [A](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3108/60716). The *same* [link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6157436?hl=en&visit_id=1-636412223390615154-2610061644&rd=1) now shows:

[image: WA3107 example]

---

Reporting currencies

## Change the currency in my performance reports

> You can view your performance reports in a different currency to your
> payment currency.
>
> To change your reporting currency:
>
> 1. In the left navigation, click Performance reports.
> 2. Click the currency drop-down <kbd>**USD** ▼</kbd> and select a new currency from the list.

```
Note that when viewing performance reports in a different currency to your payment currency,
monetary values might not be completely accurate due to currency fluctuations.
```